# Internet Routing not occurring on hostapd

Tags: linux, routing, fedora, hostapd

I have one wifi onboard device in my laptop.
Somehow, under fedora 34 with the following configuration and script...

hostapd.conf--->

```
interface=hotspot
driver=nl80211
ssid=*****
channel=7
hw_mode=g
wme_enabled=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=*********
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

connectscript -->

```
#!/bin/bash

iw phy phy0 interface add hotspot type __ap
ifconfig hotspot 192.168.1.1 up
sudo hostapd hostapd.conf
```

I am able to both simulatenously connect to a wifi network and host an ap for different network.

But the two networks are not talking to each other.

And apparently I don't understand routing in linux enough to make this work out.

Both interfaces are on different networks.

The sysctl.conf flag for forwarding ipv4 is enabled.

Oh and the connecting device is not having its ip address served via dhcp. It is manually set along with the default gateway and dns servers.

Comment: I trust those networks aren't both using the same 192.168.1.0/24 address range? If yes, change one of them to for example 192.168.2.0/24.

Comment: @Peregrino69 nope totally seperate address spaces.

Comment: One appears to have no cipd or whatever that subnet space slash notation is again.  one is 192.168.1.0/24 the other seems to be 192.168.200.0/24

Comment: @Peregrino69 I actually checked that first and turning ipv4 forwarding in sysctl didn't help either